# "make xconfig" with arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, kernel, compile

I'm trying to compile a kernel for Arch. I'm using "arch method" - abs, edit PKGBUILD and then "makepkg".

Problem is, my Arch is using xfce 4 + gnome 2, but i want to edit my config file using "xconfig" (based on qt3). It has many advantages (mostly, i like super easy search for any item and one-click locating that item in the config "tree").
I have installed qt3, but when i select "xconfig" option in "PKGBUILD" i got error `==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...` after downloading and extracting kernel. When i choose "nconfig" option everything works fine. That's why i think i miss some "xconfig" dependency.

Can anyone help me to install all needed dependencies so i can configure my Arch kernel using "xconfig", not some prehistoric console configuration tools? :)

P.S. My Arch is x86, not x64!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the qt4 package.

```
sudo pacman -S qt4
```

Your architecture shouldn't make a difference.